# Instantiate gameobjects as child of main object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is it a way for instantiate gameobjects as child of main? This is my example of code

```
void MakeCubes ()
{
    GameObject cubes = Instantiate (Cube) as GameObject;
    cubes.AddComponent <CubeScript> ();
    cubes.SetActive (true);
}
```

I'm invoking MakeCube() function every time when previous is destroyed. I ask this because I'm giving option in game that you can continue playing if you lost life. Current situation is that when you continue playing game, score isn't counting. For example. If I hit 5 cubes. I have score 5, then I lost "life". I press continue. I can hit cubes but they doesn't counting. When I hit 5 cubes it doesn't count to current score. But when I hit sixth cube it is counting from score 5 to 6.

Comment: Be careful though when doing this in UI.  Surely this is a million-times duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parent` is a attribute of `transform` so you can play with transforms to get this. Well, in your case you can do something like,

```
void MakeCubes ()
{
    GameObject cubes = Instantiate (Cube) as GameObject;
    cubes.AddComponent <CubeScript> ();
    // Replace YOUR_PARENT_GO from your parent GameObject
    cubes.transform.parent = YOUR_PARENT_GO.transform;
    cubes.SetActive (true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sue `transform.SetParent()`. Unity docs: [Transform.SetParent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parent for something that already exists in your hierarchy:

gameObject.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Name of game object").transform;